# How to Find the record with same date in an array inside a list

Tags: c#, linq

Please help me to get records from array 'attachment' having same date as that of list 'event' (in example records with attachment id=42). If two records in attachment is having same date then record with highest attachment id is need to be selected. Here Event is a list
[Fig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/165YR.png)

So that the final result should be like this.

[Fig2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsLnE.png)

I tried as following, but it doesn't work

[Fig3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDZji.png)

Comment: Post the relevant code, as text, formatted as code. If you have no code, it's too soon to be asking a question.

Comment: Also, post the relevant data as text. We can't copy text from a picture if we want to use it ourselves. You should spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a good question.

Comment: John.I tried this one - - 
                    dataEvents = dataEvents.Select(e =>
                    {
                        e.Item.Entity.Attachments = new GqlModels.UnitInfo.Status.Attachments[] { (e.Item.Entity.Attachments.Where(x =>        x.ActualDate==e.ActualDate).OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).FirstOrDefault()) };
                        return e;
                    });

Comment: in picture i put the json format - -
"data": {
        "event": [
          {
            "eventId": 0,
            "actualDate": "2022-07-19T20:00:49",
            "item": {
              "entity": {
                "id": 896,
                "attachments": [
                  {
                    "id": 42,
                    "actualDate": "2022-07-19T20:00:49"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 43,
                    "actualDate": "2022-07-20T20:00:49"
                  }
                ]}

Comment: No one should need to read the comments to understand the question. Edit your question and provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. That includes text posted as text and formatted appropriately, not as pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dataEvents = dataEvents.Select(e =>
{
    e.Item.Entity.Attachments = new Attachments[] 
            { (e.Item.Entity.Attachments.Where(x => x.ActualDate==e.ActualDate).OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).FirstOrDefault()) };
    return e;
});
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?